# How to automate read command in shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to build shell script. One of the commands used in this script is supposedly using read command demanding param to complete its execution. Now i want to pass same argument everytime for this. Can i automate this ? 
In short, how to automate read command by shell script ?

Because of some reasons i can not share actual script.

Comment: If you are building the script, you have the option of passing the value as a parameter rather than obtaining it via `read`.

Comment: You don't have to share your actual script, just a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `read` is reading from standard input, you can just redirect from a file containing the necessary data:

```
$ cat foo.txt
a
b
$ someScript.sh < foo.txt
```

or pipe the data from another command:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | someScript.sh
```